# How to escape curly brackets in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have this

```
$content = "loose text{{comments}} = {{yolo}}{{comments}} = {{yolo2}}{{comment}} = {{yolo3}}{{comment}} = {{yolo4}}loose text2";
```

and I want to escape the brackets. I read somewhere that to escape it, you double them, but even then it is not working.

I get

```
Cannot convert value "loose text{{comments}} = {{yolo}}{{comments}} = {{yolo2}}{{comment}} = {{yolo3}}{{comment}} = {{yolo4}}loose text2" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, 
because the specified node is the wrong type."
At line:1 char:1
+ $content = "loose text{{comments}} = {{yolo}}{{comments}} = {{yolo2}}{{comment}} ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Comment: Can you please clarify? The error mentions inserting an XML node and wanting to convert the example string to "System.Xml.XmlDocument". You are not showing any of that.

Comment: If u enclose in single quotes, as long as there are no variables in it, the characters shouldn't give you any trouble.

Comment: Curly braces don't need to be escaped, in either Powershell or XML.  The error message seems to indicate a different problem.

Comment: Does your code perhaps read ```[xml] $content = "loose text{{comments}}etcetc"```? That gives the same error as the one you've reported.

Answer (score 0):

The escape character in PS is the "back-tic" = `. However, in the code presented you should not have any issue just having the {} in your string.

In any case that you need to escape it just use a the sample below:

```
$content = "loose text`{comments`} = `{yolo`}`{comments`} = `{yolo2`}`{comment`} = `{yolo3`}`{comment`} = `{yolo4`}loose text2"
```